# Web scraping in R (css selectors)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have to web scrap this website link : https://www.snipes.ch/fr/c/shoes?srule=Standard&prefn1=isSale&prefv1=true&openCategory=true&sz=48 using CSS selectors.

I wanna create a df , among the variables I wanna add the original price and the discounted price, however when I select the discounted price I get vectors with both prices and I struggle to clean the data.

Here is a screen shot of the HTML format I am working on : [image]

Here is the code that I am using :

```
html_products <- html %>% html_elements("div.b-product-tile-info-container")
html_products

#Selecting product name 
product_names <- html_products %>% 
  html_element(".b-product-tile-link") %>% 
  html_text()

#Selecting product brand 
product_brand <- html_products %>% 
    html_element("span") %>% 
    html_text("brand-name") 

product_brand <-gsub("\n","", product_brand)

#Selecting product original price
product_op <- html_products %>% 
    html_element(".b-product-tile-price-item--line-through") %>% 
    html_text() 
product_op <- gsub("\n","", product_op)

#Selected discounted price 
product_dp <- html_products %>% html_element(".b-product-tile-price-item")%>% 
    html_text()
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: I don't think that the problem description matches the code you have included or I'm just not able to understand that correctly. As far as I can tell, it returns same set of prices for both selectors.

Answer (score 0):

`b-product-tile-price-item` class is used for both prices:

```html
<div class="b-product-tile-price-left">
  <span class="b-product-tile-price-outer b-product-tile-price-outer--line-through">
    <span class="b-product-tile-price-item b-product-tile-price-item--line-through"> CHF 184,90 </span>
  </span>
  <span class="b-product-tile-price-outer">
    <span class="b-product-tile-price-item"> CHF 130,00 </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

, so `html_element()` (singular) keeps picking that first match.

You could use `:not()` to exclude the first match:

```r
html_products %>% 
  html_element("span.b-product-tile-price-item:not(.b-product-tile-price-item--line-through)")
```

Or perhaps just `:last-of-type` to get the last `span span` :

```r
html_products %>% 
  html_element("span:last-of-type span")
```

Not sure if you noticed, but brand selection is not working when there are multiple color options and a carousel. And I personally prefer to iterate over containers to to build each individual record (a frame row) instead of relying on constant structure and building complete column vectors, so I'd go with something like this:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

"https://www.snipes.ch/fr/c/shoes?srule=Standard&prefn1=isSale&prefv1=true&openCategory=true&sz=48" %>% 
read_html() %>% 
  html_elements(".b-product-tile-info-container") %>% 
  purrr::map(\(ic) list(
    product = html_element(ic, ".b-product-tile-link")  %>% html_text(trim = TRUE),
    brand   = html_element(ic, ".b-product-tile-brand") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE),
    op      = html_element(ic, ".b-product-tile-price-item--line-through") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE),
    dp      = html_element(ic, ".b-product-tile-price-item:not(.b-product-tile-price-item--line-through)") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)
  )) %>% 
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 48 × 4
#>    product                         brand            op         dp        
#>    <chr>                           <chr>            <chr>      <chr>     
#>  1 Air Legacy 312 Low              JORDAN           CHF 184,90 CHF 130,00
#>  2 Sneaker Forum Low               adidas Originals CHF 99,90  CHF 70,00 
#>  3 Blazer Mid '77 Jumbo            NIKE             CHF 144,90 CHF 60,00 
#>  4 550                             New Balance      CHF 199,90 CHF 110,00
#>  5 Sneaker Response CL W           adidas Originals CHF 159,90 CHF 110,00
#>  6 L003 Neo                        Lacoste          CHF 169,90 CHF 120,00
#>  7 T-Clip                          Lacoste          CHF 149,90 CHF 100,00
#>  8 Chuck Taylor All Star Construct Converse         CHF 119,90 CHF 60,00 
#>  9 Sneaker Stan Smith              adidas Originals CHF 139,90 CHF 100,00
#> 10 Lineshot                        Lacoste          CHF 159,90 CHF 110,00
#> # ℹ 38 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>